# Minecraft Music never plays

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

As the title says, my Minecraft ingame music NEVER plays. It's in the Appdata folder, so all's OK there, my Master Volume is on max and all other sliders are on max too. But it just never plays. Only the main menu one does. All the other sounds work well.

I'm on a PC.

Comment: [Possibly related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240731/why-doesnt-the-music-in-minecraft-play-all-the-time)

Comment: I saw that post while I wrote this. No, it is not related. My music wont even start playing. And theres no fade away or anything, it's just not there.

Comment: Have you ever had it play?

Comment: Do you have in-game sounds (button clicks, noises when you interact with the environment, etc.), but no music? Also I'm assuming you're on PC, not Xbox or any other platform?

Comment: Sorry for not clear info, i am on a PC, and all other sounds work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a resource pack? Some resource packs remove all of the in-game music. Try turning it off and see if music comes on. You can also try deleting your current version jar file.

> C:\Users\ {YOUR USERNAME HERE}\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\versions

Delete the folder for the version of Minecraft you are currently playing in. (Note that this method does not erase any save data, but if you are using a modded version of Minecraft, you will have to redownload Forge) Open the launcher up and the launcher will redownload the version you were using. If none of that works, try pressing F3 + S or FN + F3 + S at the same time. Finally you can try changing the Mipmap levels in game to OFF and then back to 4.

> (ESC -> OPTIONS -> VIDEO SETTINGS)

Comment: What do Mipmap settings have to do with Audio functions? might want to clarify that point.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this error usually solves itself while your on wifi. You know this has happened when you see "missing resource pack(s). Downloaded global pack." This means it has reinstalled the standard pack. If the issue persist, Delete and reinstall minecraft. ~**Kaden F.**

P.S careful when deleting minecraft, you will lose your world's unless you extract them by copying their save file via a file explorer.